# How to add a default value to get_option if it's used as a variable?

Tags: plugins, theme-customizer, options

How to add a default value to `get_option` if it's used as a **variable** ?

The code :

```php
$my_options = get_option( 'my_options' ); // Associative Array 'my_options'.

<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: <?php 
echo esc_attr( $my_options['my_background_color_option'] ); ?>">
```

I want to avoid an `Undefined index error` or a `false return`.

Is the following correct ?

```php
<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: <?php 
echo esc_attr( $my_options['my_background_color_option'] ) ? $my_options['my_background_color_option'] : '#000'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

So I originally suggested normalizing the options array; i.e. merging saved values with the default values. And this does solve the "undefined index" notice:

```php
$my_options = wp_parse_args( get_option( 'my_options' ), [
    'my_background_color_option' => '#000',
    // ... other args.
] );
```

But to make sure that an option is not empty (e.g. not `''`, `false`, `null`, `0` or `[]`), you can use `empty()` like so: (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065980/6837428) and yourself/OP)

```php
<div id="identifier" class="classname" style="background-color: <?php echo esc_attr( // wrapped for clarity
    ( ! empty( $my_options['my_background_color_option'] ) ) ?
        $my_options['my_background_color_option'] : '#000'
); ?>">
```

There's also the `array_merge()`, but the above is indeed something that is good for validating an option. ( But sorry, I was focused on the "undefined index" thing and kinda forgot the (avoiding a) `false return`... =) )

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for sharing your method. But if I have 100 options (as an example), the code would be huge. You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065980/6837428). It's exactly what I was looking for. thanks again.

Comment: Lol, sorry, I was focused on the "default" thing. :) And I hope you don't mind the edits - I just thought I should correct the answer. =)